# Variadic arguments, using Type Families instead of Multi-param Typeclasses

Tags: haskell, variadic-functions, type-families

Here's what I've got, expressed with MultiParamTypeClasses:

```
class ListResultMult r a where
  lstM :: a -> [a] -> r

listM :: ListResultMult r a => a -> r
listM a = lstM a []


instance ListResultMult r a => ListResultMult (a -> r) a where
  lstM a as x = lstM x $ a:as

instance ListResultMult [a] a where
  lstM a as = reverse $ a:as

instance Show a => ListResultMult (IO ()) a where
  lstM a as = print . reverse $ a:as
```

Here's what I tried, using TypeFamilies (TypeSynonymInstances didn't help):

```
class ListResultFam r where
  type Elem r :: *
  lstF :: Elem r -> [Elem r] -> r

listFam :: ListResultFam r => Elem r -> r
listFam a = lstF a []


-- Illegal type synonym family application in instance: Elem r -> r
-- in the instance declaration for `ListResultFam (Elem r -> r)'
instance ListResultFam r => ListResultFam (Elem r -> r) where
  type Elem (Elem r -> r) = Elem r
  lstF a as x = lstF x $ a:as

instance ListResultFam [a] where
  type Elem [a] = a
  lstF a as = reverse $ a:as
```

Is there any way to accomplish this with Type Families? Why is this an "illegal" type synonym family application?

Comment: I don't know the rules exactly, but I'm suspicious of (Elem r -> r) as a pattern in a type family, when Elem is not a type constructor but, in effect, a defined function. Here, it might be possible to match r right of the ->, then check that what's left of -> agrees with Elem r, but in general, allowing type synonym families in patterns for type synonym families would require them to be invertible.

Comment: I was thinking of it this way: given that `r` is a `ListResultFam`, this means that `Elem r` is some specific type. It seems logically sound, although the implementation details may not be all there.

Comment: Look at the example Daniel Wagner gave in the other post, you need an equality constraint `(Elem r ~ a)` and then use `type Elem (a -> r) = a`.

Comment: Whoops, I accidentally answered this in your other question! Sorry about that, I hadn't seen this one yet.

Comment: [Link to Daniel Wagner's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031288/variadic-list-constructor-how-to-default-to-the-correct-type-and-get-type-safet/8031515#8031515), for posterity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Type families aren't a replacement for multi param type classes, rather they replace functional dependencies.

This is because type families allow a mapping from one type to another, which is similar to what functional dependencies do with multi param type classes. Ie:

```
class Collection col e | col -> e where
   getHead :: col -> e

instance Collection [a] a where
   getHead = head
```

can be represented with type families as:

```
class Collection col where
  type CollectionHead col :: *
  getHead :: col -> CollectionHead col

instance Collection [a] where
   type CollectionHead [a] = a
   getHead = head
```

However they cannot replace a multi param type class without functional dependencies. Eg

```
class Converter a b where
  convert :: a -> b

instance Converter Int String where
  convert = show

instance Converter Int [Int] where
  convert x = [x]
```

Cannot be done by removing the b param and using type families. You could do something like this:

```
class Converter a where
   type Target a :: *
   convert :: a -> Target a

instance Converter Int where
   type Target Int = String
   convert = show
```

However it isn't possible to write the second instance, as it require a duplicate instance `Converter Int`.

---

With regards to your program, you can see instantly that there are no functional dependencies, just multiple parameter type classes. You therefor cannot do a straight conversion to type families with this.