# Resolving ambiguities for overloaded functions

Tags: haskell, typeclass, overloading

I want to have an overloaded function in Haskell.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
class Foo a where
   foo :: a

instance Foo (String -> Int) where
   foo = length

instance Foo String where
   foo = "world"
```

However such overloading deals very poorly with type ambiguities. `print $ foo "hello"` would result in an error, while `print $ length "hello"` works fine. However, provided that my list of instances is fixed, there shouldn't be a technical reason why Haskell can't realize that the only instance of `foo :: String -> a` is `foo :: String -> Int`. Can I have Haskell make this realization?

Comment: Is this really what you want to do? But to the question: no I don't think it can be done this general.

Comment: @Carsten, I could live with having function `fooLen` and `fooStr`, but I think overloading is a lot more comfortable.

Comment: The problem is that maybe you export your function (`printFoo` or whatever) and then if someone uses it and adds an instance `instance Foo (String -> Double)` he would be in trouble

Comment: Also this might be a case of YAGNI - don't introduce type-classes to quickly (just my 50cts. of course)

Comment: "... provided that my list of instances is fixed, ..." - but type classes are open - i.e. later you could add an instance in another module.

Comment: @Carsten, that's the point. Any possible solution would probably involve preventing the class from being extended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easy to do in this particular case. Simply:

```
instance a ~ Int => Foo (String -> a) where foo = length
```

Comment: +1 of course *doh* did not thing of this - nice *workaround* - of course I still think a class like `Foo` here is just a symptom for another problem ;)

Comment: as as side note just constraining to `Num` and using `genericLength` should work too: `instance Num a => Foo (String -> a) where foo = genericLength` maybe this is easier to understand as I think that *equality constraints* are not widely known (at least to beginners)

Comment: Great. Though I had to add *IncoherentInstances* to get the second instance to work. Where can I read up why this works?

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė You definitely shouldn't need incoherent instances, and shouldn't turn it on even if you think you need it. What is the second instance? The two you give in your question work just fine for me without incoherent instances.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė For "why this works", I explain a little bit in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10777583/791604). GHC looks at instance heads (only!) when choosing which instance to use, then requires the context for that instance to hold. So anything that matches `String -> a` uses that instance, then verifies *after* we know that we're using that instance that `a` is actually `Int`.

Comment: @DanielWagner, then I probably changed it wrong. I did `instance a ~ String => Foo a where foo = "world"`: [A working version with incoherent instances](http://ideone.com/MrJjMi), [and the same code failing without it](http://ideone.com/YqujdK).

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė Yes, don't do that. Leave `instance Foo String` as-is. [A working version with no incoherent instances.](http://ideone.com/49124L)

Comment: @DanielWagner, but your code explicitly states that foo should be `String`, rather than `String->Int`. I don't want that. I want it to figure out that only `String` is an instance of `Show`. What's so bad about IncoherentInstances anyway?

Answer (score 0):

In your case GHCI knows, that `foo :: String -> ??`

We are going to change signature to `String -> Int`:

```
print (foo "hello" :: Int)
```

Comment: I think the question was why this is needed ;) (and if you can make the compiler find it by itself)