# Result type of a polyvariadic function in haskell

Tags: haskell, polyvariadic

While studying polyvariadic functions in Haskell I stumbled across the following SO questions:

[How to create a polyvariadic haskell function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467279/how-to-create-a-polyvariadic-haskell-function)

[Haskell, polyvariadic function and type inference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33333614/haskell-polyvariadic-function-and-type-inference)

and thought I will give it a try by implementing a function which takes a variable number of strings and concatenates/merges them into a single string:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

class MergeStrings r where
    merge :: String -> r
instance MergeStrings String where
    merge = id
instance (MergeStrings r) => MergeStrings (String -> r) where
    merge acc = merge . (acc ++)
```

This works so far if I call merge with at least one string argument and if I provide the final type.

```hs
foo :: String
foo = merge "a" "b" "c"
```

Omitting the final type results in an error, i.e., compiling the following

```hs
bar = merge "a" "b" "c"
```

results in

```
test.hs:12:7: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘t0’ arising from a use of ‘merge’
      prevents the constraint ‘(MergeStrings t0)’ from being solved.
      Relevant bindings include bar :: t0 (bound at test.hs:12:1)
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘t0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance MergeStrings r => MergeStrings (String -> r)
          -- Defined at test.hs:6:10
        instance MergeStrings String -- Defined at test.hs:4:10
    • In the expression: merge "a" "b" "c"
      In an equation for ‘bar’: bar = merge "a" "b" "c"
   |
12 | bar = merge "a" "b" "c"
   |
```

The error message makes perfect sense since I could easily come up with, for example

```
bar :: String -> String
bar = merge "a" "b" "c"

baz = bar "d"
```

rendering `bar` not into a single string but into a function which takes and returns one string.

Is there a way to tell Haskell that the result type must be of type `String`? For example, `Text.Printf.printf "hello world"` evaluates to type `String` without explicitly defining.

Comment: To clarify: you seem to be saying that, when the type of `merge a b c etc…` cannot be inferred, you want GHC to infer a type of `String`, otherwise use the inferred type. Is this interpretation correct? I can’t think of any way to do this, but I wouldn’t be able to conclusively say that it’s impossible either.

Comment: By the way: it looks like your `printf` example only works because `PrintfType` has an instance for `IO`; when testing in GHCi, any type which can be specialised to `IO` will automatically be run. If I define `instance (a ~ ()) => MergeStrings (IO a) where merge = putStrLn`, `bar = merge "a" "b" "c"` works for me as well in GHCi. And, outside GHCi, `printf "hello world"` results in an ambiguous type variable error, in exactly the same way that `bar = merge "a" "b" "c"` does.

Comment: For clarification: I didn't want GHC to infer the result type but rather define the result type at the definition side of merge such that when using merge I do not have to provide the result type. Your observations regarding GHCi and IO are really interesting I will play around with them, too! Seems like @max-taldykin nailed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`printf` works without type annotation because of [type defaulting](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#type-defaulting-in-ghci) in GHCi. The same mechanism that allows you to eval `show $ 1 + 2` without specifying concrete types.

[GHCi tries to evaluate expressions of type `IO a`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#actions-at-prompt), so you just need to add appropriate instance for `MergeStrings`:

```
instance (a ~ ()) => MergeStrings (IO a) where
    merge = putStrLn
```

Comment: Oh gosh you are right :) I didn't expect it to be a GHCi thing. Using just GHC, then `foo = printf "hello world"` without type annotations also results in a compile error. Thanks for lifting this mystery!

Answer (score 2):

Brad [*(in a comment)*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62114605/result-type-of-a-polyvariadic-function-in-haskell#comment109859940_62114605) and Max are not wrong saying that the defaulting of `printf "…" …` to `IO ( )` is the reason for it working in `ghci` without type annotations. But it is not the end of the story. There are things we can do to make your definition of `bar` work.

First, I should mention the ***«monomorphism restriction»*** — an obscure and unintuitive type inference rule we have in Haskell. For whatever reason, the designers of Haskell decided that a top level definition without a type signature should have no polymorphic variables in its inferred type — that is, be monomorphic. `bar` is polymorphic, so you can see that it would be affected.

Some type classes *(particularly numbers)* have **defaulting rules** that allow you to say `x = 13` without a type signature and have it inferred that `x :: Integer` — or whatever other type you set as default. Type defaulting is only available for a few blessed classes, so you cannot have it for your own class, and without a designated default GHC cannot decide what particular monomorphic type to choose.

But you can do other things, beside defaulting, to make the type checker happy — either:

- [Disable the monomorphism restriction.](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#switching-off-the-dreaded-monomorphism-restriction)
- Assign an explicit polymorphic type signature: `bar :: MergeStrings r => r`

Now `bar` is polymorphic and works as you would expect. See:

```
λ putStrLn bar
abc
λ putStrLn (bar "x")
abcx
λ putStrLn (bar "x" "y")
abcxy
```

You can also use defaulting to make expressions such as `show bar` work. Since `Show` is among the classes that you can default when [extended default rules](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#extension-ExtendedDefaultRules) are enabled, you can issue `default (String)` in the module where you want to use `show bar` and it will work as you would expect.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer! I wasn't aware of this monomorphic restriction at all. Like you said, adding an explicit polymorphic type signature solves my problem and it also feels good to me :) so I will go with that.

Comment: IOW this answers the OP's question "Is there a way to tell Haskell that the result type must be of type String?" with "you shouldn't, keep it polymorphic instead, and then the calling context will determine the type in each case"!. :) nice.